# Carry phone and internet signal over powerline

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, phone, rj-45, rj-11

I want to connect my phone with RJ11 and STB (IPTV) with RJ45 in another room, while extending the wifi signal.

Regarding the phone, is it possible to do the following:
Router with RJ11 -> Adapter from RJ11 to RJ45 -> Connect RJ45 to powerline -> On the other end, adapter from RJ45 to RJ11 -> Connect to phone

Would a PLC like like TL-WPA4226KIT or TL-WPA4230PKIT do the job?

Comment: No; Kits like TL-WPA4226KIT would it support your goal

Comment: Is the phone an IP phone? Or a standard analog?  Seems like it's analog given the RJ11, IP phones that I've seen use RJ45.  Anyway if it an analog phone, then no.